# NSError * returned with bad address - why?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In the code below, the NSError, when returned, shows in XCode with a class type of 'HomeViewController' - one of my view controllers.  This would make sense if I'd done something out of the ordinary with the double pointer, but I didn't.  Why is this happening?  Is there some stupid mistake in my code, a bug in Core Data, or ????

Hopefully I'm not making a fool of myself !

```
self->ctx = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                          entityForName:@"Street" inManagedObjectContext:self->ctx];

NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                    initWithKey:@"street" ascending:YES];
NSArray* sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sortDescriptor, nil];


[request setEntity:entityDescription];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError * error;
NSArray *array = [self->ctx executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if(error!=nil){
    NSLog(@"%@", @"Critical model error search");
}
_streets = array;
```

Comment: Don't use `self->` to access ivars.

Comment: @bbum  thanks for the best practice.. why is that though?

Comment: It is a convention.  There is no real harm (save for considering whether or not there is behavior on your accessors that might be critical), but you don't see it done outside of esoteric situations (like the implementation of -copy methods).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly the method you're using (`[self->ctx executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]`) doesn't set its argument to `nil` if there isn't an error, just to the error if one occurs. <strike>Initialize your variable to `nil`: `NSError *error = nil;`.</strike>

As pointed out in the comments, you have to check the return value of the call, and only if it's `nil` or `NO` (depending on the declared return type) is the `NSError` pointer guaranteed valid (incl. nil), even if it was valid going in.  So instead of `if(error != nil)`, use `if(!array)` or `if(array == nil)`.

Comment: This is indeed correct, and in general Cocoa requires that you check the direct return value before using the NSError, not whether the error is nil. The error is [guaranteed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1) to be valid if the method indicates failure, but the reverse -- that it will be nil for success -- is not guaranteed, even if you set it to nil beforehand.

Comment: Local vars are pointed at junk. You must set to nil (or NULL). The analyser will point that out too :-)

Comment: ... unless you compile with ARC - then pointers to objects are initialized to nil.

Comment: ...and there's still no guarantee that it will _remain_ `nil` after being passed in.

Comment: Note that there is **no reason to set the local variable to `nil`** prior to making the call and it is **incorrect to test the `error` value without testing the return value first**.   The last line of this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Kind of a jerk move by apple to not guarantee they won't vandalize your valid pointers.

Comment: (Nice clarification, btw. Thanks.) Not really;  the return value *must* indicate success/fail exactly because you can pass `NULL` for error such that the method being called knows not to waste any time calculating (potentially expensive) error information.  Thus, requiring that you always check the return value ensures consistency while not guaranteeing that the pointer will remain untouched maximized internal implementation flexibility, performance, and -- again -- consistency.   This was a considered design decision.

Comment: Thanks for all the discussion, this is very interesting especially because I copied this code from another project where it works completely fine.  I see now it's a dangling pointer issue.

Comment: @bbum there is one exception to the rule I've sadly come across: http://mikeabdullah.net/nsurl-bookmark-error-handling.html

Comment: @MikeAbdullah A bug that has since been fixed?

Comment: I wish I knew; to my annoyance I don't seem to have filed a radar. The only way to know without some Apple docs/release note is for me to back out my special handling code and see if it crashes for anybody :(

Answer (score 0):

This keeps coming up.  So, some concrete examples.

There is no reason to initialize the NSError to nil. The one caveat is if the object you are calling with the &err is nil, you'll get a false failure and checking an un-initialized error will blow up.  *However*, that failure mode is very different than an attempt that leads to failure and, really, you should avoid the nil recipient case (imagine if your managed object context is unexpectedly nil--  you probably have a much bigger issues than a false error).

This is a perfectly valid implementation of a method that returns BOOL and takes an NSError**.  Valid, but obviously contrived.  However, this kind of thing does happen in a many layered API.

```
 - (BOOL)doThis:(NSError**)chaffin
 {
    if (chaffin) *chaffin = 0x42;
    return YES;
 }
```

Calculating the error can be expensive.  Pass null for the error parameter if you only need to know success/failure, but not why.